# Framework model for AIR and Android applications.

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flex4, cairngorm

Can someone please suggest me some good framework (officially released) to follow for developing AIR Desktop and android applications just like Cairngorm for flex web applications.

Thanks 
Piyush G.

Comment: Just use Flex in AIR with any Flex-suitable framework. It will work on android too.

Comment: AIR 2.5 SDK supports Android OS.  Release Notes:  http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/868/cpsid_86822.html

Answer (score 0):

Try **Flash Buider Buritto**, it has the mobile publishing options and also the HALO flex mobile framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask first if you have attempted to use Flash Builder "Burrito" on Labs http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashbuilder_burrito/ without using a framework yet? While these is nothing that I am aware of that would prevent you from using Cairngorm (I assume you mean Cairngorm 3) or any other framework for mobile Flex (other options I've seen include Swiz and Parsley), you may not find you require it depending on the nature and complexity of your mobile application.

Part of the reason for this is because the mobile Flex framework includes a new concept of a view stack and a view navigator to manage the view stack that differs from your past Flex development work. You either push a view to the stack (whereby it becomes the active view and other views are no longer active or stored in memory though session information is kept in the PersistenceManager) or pop views off the stack (whereby the prior view becomes the active view and the session state should be restored by the PersitenceManager). You can pass data back and forth as you push and pop views from the stack. I have a post that covers some of the details of how that is managed http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/passing-data-across-views-in-flex-mobile